# Meeting and invitations / How to model invitations mechanism in a DDD context?

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

In a context of domain-driven design:

My domain is about meetings and invitations sending.
An example:

**A user can create a meeting called "MyMeeting" and he can invite users of his choice through some dedicated "invitations".**

I read Vaughn Vernon's book (IDDD), and I concluded that **there isn't  invariant** between `Meeting` and `Invitation`.

So, I started creating both distinct aggregates roots:

- `Meeting`   (id, name, etc.)
- `Invitation` (meetingId, occurredOn, receiver (the targeted user))

**I realised that multiple invitations might be sent at once.**
So I thought about creating a special query in `InvitationRepository` aiming to save all invitations at once:

`void addAll(List<Invitation> invitations)`

The issue is that it introduces an incoherence with the structure of the `Invitation` aggregate.
Explanation:
The structure involves each `Invitation` to have its own associated `meetingId`.
Whereas `addAll` is aimed to add multiple invitations concerning the same `MeetingId`; in other words: common to each invitation.

Thus it would be ... ugly to have this kind of implementation due to the current structure, if I want to avoid multiple database queries:

```
void addAll(List<Invitation> invitations) {

    //meetingId supposed to be the same across those invitations, 
    //an ugly way to retrieve it would be : 
    MeetingId meetingId = invitations.get(0).getMeetingId(); 
    Date occurredOn = invitations.get(0).getOccurredOn();
    List<User> receivers = new ArrayList();

    for(invitation: Invitations) {
      receivers.add(invitation.getReceiver());
    }

    //then perform the query saving all invitations at once
    //=> one invitation for each receiver
}
```

What would be a good way to handle the case of saving multiple `Invitations` at once?
Should the domain structure be altered?

---

I thought about those signatures in `InvitationRepository`:

```
void add(List<Invitation> invitations)            
void addAll(List<Invitation> invitations, MeetingId meetingId, DateTime: occurredOn)
```

Or even with a wrapper called Invitations:

```
class Invitations {  //note the plurality
   MeetingId meetingId; 
   DateTime occurredOn;
   List<Invitation> invitations;
   //........ 
}
```

=> `void addAll(Invitations invitations)`
   Saving **nested** invitations (aggregate roots), in a same database query.

This way, in case of `addAll` implementation, I would not pick the `meetingId` and `occurredOn` from the `invitations itself`, leading to a kind a DRY violation but keeping the whole far less ugly.

What do you think?

Comment: Could you demonstrate how your snippet would enable a single query to commit all invitations ? Pseudo-code will be enough

Comment: I'm using Neo4J, and with Neo4j, there is some good keywords for Cypher queries aiming to loop over some arrays (in this case invitations list), the whole in the exact same query process. (similar to what we could do with PL/SQL)

Comment: If you provide me with an example I can probably edit my answer to use this on the encapsulated list of invitations

Comment: The whole OP is about aggregate roots and other specific terms to DDD. 
The tricky thing is to adapt this use case to DDD technical strategies. 
Otherwise, obviously I would adhere totally to your solution ;)

Comment: Hem ok it's frustrating for me to not get what you want but I'll give up for now :p Good luck

Comment: I updated my OP, perhaps with a kind of potential solution.
Maybe it would be more clear what I expect.      
I appreciate your implication by the way :) ;)

Comment: Your third snippet is equivalent to the first two (proposed signatures) unless `Invitations` is constructed like in my answer. My real concern is about factorizing out the meeting id and the date of the meeting without actually checking that all invitations share the same values. I thought it was your concern as well but it does not seem to be the case...

Comment: yes, actually it's very subtil, but it is very similar to the essence of your solution, I can confirm. The objective was to fit/keep DDD component's morphology.

Comment: Haha my final words on this will be that I wouldn't let a "Domain-Driven Design" *drive* me.Contrarily to books and general designs, we programmers can use good judgement on particular situations to write better code. Drive your design or be driven by it, that is the question :D

Comment: A proper implementation of the addAll method is one that does not care about business rules. If invitations are independent aggregates then the repository should treat them as such. There should not be a different semantic between calling add in a loop or calling addAll. List<Invitation> invitations = meeting.inviteAll(invitees); repository.addAll(invitations);

Comment: +1 to what plalx said. I wouldn't call it `addAll()`, by the way (all of what ?) but `addMany()` or something similar. Besides, if you're just interested in the performance aspect and not the immediate consistency, how many invitations would you write at the same time ? What kind of DB is it ? Have you benchmarked "rifle" insertions vs one bulk insert ?

Comment: `addAll()` is the standard of a `Set` element. Repositories are based on Set convention. I'm using Neo4J in Rest mode, so basically, one query = one round-trip to the database server.

Comment: @guillaume31 Did you receive the DDD question I sent you by email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper implementation of the `addAll` method is one that does not care about business rules. If invitations are independent aggregates then the repository should treat them as such. There should not be a different semantic between calling `add` in a loop or calling `addAll`.

```
Set<Invitation> invitations = meeting.inviteAll(invitees);           

repository.addAll(invitations);
```

Here `inviteAll` method encapsulates the business logic necessary to ensure that all invitations will be linked to the same meeting.

If there are some persitence optimizations that can be made when all invitations are sharing the same `meetingId` then nothing prevents you from inspecting all invitations in the repository and see if there are possible optimizations or not.

For instance, you could loop all invitations and group them by `meetingId` using a `Map`.

Comment: Good answer, completely agree. That's exactly what I've eventually done this morning. Performance optimization in this case is orthogonal to design consistency and should not affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do this ?

```
public class InvitationBulkRequest {
     private final List<Invitation> invitations = new ArrayList<>();
     private final MeetingId meetingId;
     private final DateTime occurredOn

     public InvitationBulkRequest(MeetingId meetingId, DateTime occurredOn) {
         this.meetingId = Objects.requireNonNull(meetingId);
         this.occurredOn = Objects.requireNonNull(occurredOn);
     }

     public void invite(User recipient) {
         invitations.add(new Invitation(meetingId, occurredOn, recipient);
     }

     public void send() {
         invitations.forEach(Invitation::send);
     }
}
```

This way, you nicely encapsulate the common data bewteen all invitations and make sure they all are consistent.

Comment: What about the Invitation Repository?
In your solution, you loop over invitations to send them, thus involving multiple database queries, what I want to avoid.

Comment: I don't get your question. I think I'm answering your concern though

Comment: See my updated previous comment. Your solution doesn't fit with classical DDD technical components (repository being one of them)

Comment: The trick is to have a nice solution (like you did since it makes sense) but at the same time, being consistent with traditional DDD architecture.

Comment: What I called a bulk request is most likely what you called the repository. You can call it whatever you want it remains the same principle

Comment: A possibility would be:   `InvitationRepository#addAll(List<Invitations> invitations, MeetingId meetingId)`. But wouldn't it be "weird" to have this meetingId parameter making "useless"/"ignored" the ones contained within each invitation?

Comment: About your first comment that you edited, please keep in mind I have no idea of your internals or requirements outside this question. This code is just an illustration of how encapsulation can be achieved, it's not supposed to be directly pluggable in your project.

Comment: @Mik378 to me it does not make sense to mix invitations in a list that could contain invitations from different meetings. It's just wrong, which is why I proposed a solution ensuring they are all consistent

Comment: Yes, I well understand. The OP is not about encapsulation, it's especially about consistency between Repository and Domain in a case of batch.

Comment: In this case, why not having an aggregate root named: "Invitations" (plural), itself containing `MeetingId` and `List<Invitation>`

Comment: Isn't your problem the fact that with a random list of invitations you may have inconsistent meeting ids ? If that's your problem, encapsulation is definitely the solution

Comment: @Mik378 again, the name does not matter. What you are proposing is what I implemented in my question with a different name

Comment: I never mentioned the "fear" of inconsistent meeting ids. My OP never points out that I don't have any use case letting a user sending multiple invitations for distinct meetings, at once.

Comment: Yes, it's very similar to your solution :)

Comment: This discussion is a bit confusing to me, mostly because I inferred the meaning of the question from the snippet, and that I'm not familiar with the concepts you are mentionning (DDD, "aggregate", "aggregate root"). Hopefully the answer will still be relevant :p

Comment: The answer is not really relevant since your solution would involve multiple database queries ;)

Comment: If the question was strictly about encapsulation, believe me I would not ask the question :), since it would be obvious.

Comment: @Mik378 haha such a misunderstanding bewteen us. Nothing prevents you from using the exact same encapsulation and add a single entry for all invitations at the same time. You never mentionned such requirement

Comment: Excerpt my OP: "So I thought about creating a special query in InvitationRepository aiming to save all invitations at once"

Comment: "Save" is a vague term, it could mean anything, it never implies it's adding an entry in a DB with a single call. Anyway, I think the question needs some refining because I was far from getting all the requirements from it. By the way, I think the anwer depends on how your DB is structured because if you have a table containing all the invitations there's no way you can go around making multiple queries... and that's ok unless you make meetings of a million attendees

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your design is sound, though?  You may be trying to shoehorn a slightly skewed design into DDD speak.

I would think that a meeting has *some* invariants.  Perhaps we need at least 2 participants.  A meeting with one person is rather tedious.  Now I assume the invitation has *some* relevant to this.  Could it be that the invitation is the mechanism used to notify the participant and track acceptance?

Shuffling some of these things around may give you a clue as to how to address your issue.  Maybe you could have `Meeting` 1-* `Participant` that is represented by an `Invitation` in the same way that `Order` 1-* `Product` is represented by an `OrderItem`.

Comment: Participation is another notion, in my domain, distinct from the OP. Meeting and Participation nested entity have invariant indeed ( like the maximum amount of expected participants). My OP is about Invitation. A Participation is triggered by the acceptance of an invitation. We could send 100 invitations, for only 10 available places. So the first 10 users accepting the invitations would take the places.

Comment: Ah, this is why knowing the domain is so important :) --- seems as though the invitations would be part of the `Meeting`.  Does it *really* make sense for an invitation to exist without a `Meeting`?  Perhaps even a `MeetingInvitation` could exist where the `HasBeenAccepted` can be set.  The `Meeting` could have a `Open` / `Closed` / `Cancelled` status along with the `MaximumNumberOfSeats` or some such.  It definitely seems as though the relationship between the two may be closer and should perhaps be modeled that way since you seem to *have* to keep track of those invites per meeting.

Comment: There are no invariants between Invitation and Meeting. 
They should be transitionally independent. Also, if I want to add a 809th invitation afterwards (invitation are not forced to be sent at once), I don't want to load all the invitations collection just to add it. It would consume memory for no real reason.

Comment: Can I add an invitation to a meeting that is in the past?  How about a meeting that has been fully booked?  Can I send 3 invitations to the same person?  Perhaps there are no real invariants in which case you can arbitrarily add invitations, sure.  Having a large number of items will require one to reconsider the design.  Perhaps a `MeetingBlock` of sorts.  In the same way one could argue that adding the 809th item to an `Order` would be a waste of memory, no? :)  Anyway, these are just some things to consider along the design.  However, seems you've made up your mind, so go with that ;)